# jQuery selector help - how to find element whose ID starts and ends with specific characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page that's created dynamically. It can have a number of different radio buttons with ID's like so:

```
<input type="radio" id="cc-radio-opt-0" />
<input type="radio" id="cc-radio-opt-1" />
<input type="radio" id="gc-radio-opt-0" />
<input type="radio" id="gc-radio-opt-1" />
```

In order to write change functions, I'm doing something like this:

```
$('[id^=cc-radio-opt-]').live("change", function() {
    var idx = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop(); 
});
```

This works well. But now, inside that change function, I need to hide a bunch of other related fields. They are named like this:

```
<input type="text" id="cc-number-0" />
<input type="text" id="cc-month-0" />
<input type="text" id="gc-number-0" />
<input type="text" id="gc-month-0" />
<input type="text" id="cc-number-1" />
<input type="text" id="cc-month-1" />
<input type="text" id="gc-number-1" />
<input type="text" id="gc-month-1" />
```

I need to be able to grab all the fields whose IDs begin with "cc" and end with the same number as the radio button that's been clicked (determined by the `idx` variable. I know I can get all the fields that start with "cc" by doing this:

```
$('[id^=cc-]');
```

But how can I also indicate that they need to end with whatever `idx` is? In other words, if the `cc-radio-opt-1` radio is clicked, how can I get only `cc-number-1` and `cc-month-1`?

Comment: No, they are NOT duplicate IDs. If you look more carefully, you'll see that one group starts with cc and the other starts with gc.

Comment: for future reference. .live has been deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/
you should be using .on instead
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @iAmClownShoe - I'm aware, but due to the CMS we're working with, we're stuck with an older version of jQuery.

Comment: fair enough. like i said, for future reference :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you were almost there...
`$('[id^=cc-][id$=1]')`

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/nr3ad/

Answer (score 4):

Filter your selector using the "ends with" selector.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

```
$('[id^="cc-"]').filter('[id$="idx"');
```

And make sure to include quotes.

Comment: is `.filter()` faster than `$('[id^=cc-][id$=1]')`?

Comment: @mpapec Possibly, but that would be a micro-optimization. Use whatever method best fits the needs of your application.