# How do I select all IDs containing a single character difference? (Wildcards in Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I've got some fields defined by a third party app:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eventinstance_set-0-DELETE" id="id_eventinstance_set-0-DELETE">
<input type="checkbox" name="eventinstance_set-1-DELETE" id="id_eventinstance_set-1-DELETE">
<input type="checkbox" name="eventinstance_set-2-DELETE" id="id_eventinstance_set-2-DELETE">
```

I need to use jQuery see if any of them are checked, but I don't know how to select them.

if I use `input[id^=eventinstance_set]` it will include multiple non-relevant fields such as this one:

`<input type="text" name="eventinstance_set-0-end" id="id_eventinstance_set-0-end">`

on the other hand if I use `input[id$=DELETE]` it would get other nonrelevant fields.

What's the proper way for me to evaluate for `id=eventinstance_set-*-DELETE`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530361/jquery-selector-help-how-to-find-element-whose-id-starts-and-ends-with-specifi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142644/jquery-selector-for-matching-at-start-and-end-of-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple attribute selectors, it returns the elements that match all of them.

```
$("[id^=eventinstance_set][id$=DELETE]")
```